# Inserir linha divisória programaticamente

Tags: java, android

Como posso colocar uma linha divisória programaticamente utilizando java?
O código XML é:

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="#ddd" />
```

Comment: Você quer inserir essa linha onde? Por exemplo, ListView, Menu, RecyclerView, Layout, etc.?! É importante deixar detalhar isso na pergunta, pois talvez, digo talvez, para cada caso há uma solução diferente.

Comment: Quero inserir a linha em um layout. Seu como inserir um Textview ou uma imagem. Agora quero uma linha divisória entre o texto e a imagem.

Answer (score 2):

Por exemplo, para inserir em um `LinearLayout`, primeiro precisa instancia-la:

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

Depois basta criar uma `View` programaticamente desta forma abaixo, usando o método `setLayoutParams` para definir as configurações de largura `View`:

```
View divider = new View(this);
divider.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
linear.addView(divider);
```

É possível definir também uma cor usando uma cor estática da [classe Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html). Veja:

```
linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Certíssimoooo

Comment: @FabricioChavesJorhge A resposta te atente ou precisa de mais alguma informação?!